# Не отправляются данные на другую страницу

Tags: php, post, php7, html-form

Написал небольшой тест на PHP, но он не работает. Данные почему-то не отправляются на другую страницу. Обращаюсь к глобальной переменной $_POST - ничего нет.
Вот страница теста:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='ru'>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no'>
    <style>
        /*
        html, body {
            background-color: #000;
        }
        */

        h3 {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Тест</h3>
    <form active="http://localhost/result.php" method="POST">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>1. Каким является язык PHP?</legend>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_1" value="A">Комилируемый</input></p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_1" value="B">Интерпретируемый</input></p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>2. Как получить данные из POST-запроса?</legend>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_2" value="A">Через функцию getPostData()</input></p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_2" value="B">Через переменную $_POST</input></p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_2" value="C">Через константу POST</input></p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>3. Что делает оператор break при вызове внутри цикла?</legend>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_3" value="A">Переводит цикл на следующую итерацию, обрывая выполнение текущей</input></p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_3" value="B">Останавливает работу цикла</input></p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>4. Какой тип значения будет в переменной $a после выполнения кода $a = '123';?</legend>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_4" value="A">int</input></p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_4" value="B">string</input></p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_4" value="C">boolean</input></p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_4" value="D">float</input></p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>5. С помощью какого символа в PHP можно склеить 2 строки в одну?</legend>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_5" value="A">Cимвол доллара</input></p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_5" value="B">Cимвол запятой</input></p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_5" value="C">Cимвол точки</input></p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>6. Как нужно создавать новый массив?</legend>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_6" value="A">$a = new Array();</input></p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_6" value="B">$a = null;</input></p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_6" value="C">$a = [];</input></p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_6" value="D">$a = array();</input></p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>7. Возможно ли на PHP писать рекурсивные функции?</legend>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_7" value="A">Нет</input></p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_7" value="B">Да</input></p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>8. С помощью какой функции можно удалить Cookie?</legend>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_8" value="A">deletecookie</input></p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_8" value="B">readcookie</input></p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_8" value="C">getcookie</input></p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_8" value="D">setcookie</input></p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>9. Как присвоить переменной значение?</legend>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_9" value="A">$x = 5</input></p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_9" value="B">$x == 5</input></p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_9" value="C">$x => 5</input></p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_9" value="D">$x === 5</input></p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>10. Можно ли встраивать PHP-код в HTML-код?</legend>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_10" value="A">Нет</input></p>
            <p><input type="radio" name="question_10" value="B">Да</input></p>
        </fieldset>
        <button type="submit">Завершить тест</button>
        <button type="reset">Очистить</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Страница на которую отправляются данные:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang='ru'>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no'>
    <style>
        /*
        html, body {
            background-color: #000;
        }
        */
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <h3>Результаты теста</h3>
    <?php 
        $result_test = 0;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
            switch ($i) {
                case 1: if ($_POST['question_'.$i] == 'B') $result_test++; break;
                case 2: if ($_POST['question_'.$i] == 'B') $result_test++; break;
                case 3: if ($_POST['question_'.$i] == 'B') $result_test++; break;
                case 4: if ($_POST['question_'.$i] == 'B') $result_test++; break;
                case 5: if ($_POST['question_'.$i] == 'C') $result_test++; break;
                case 6: if ($_POST['question_'.$i] == 'A') $result_test++; break;
                case 7: if ($_POST['question_'.$i] == 'B') $result_test++; break;
                case 8: if ($_POST['question_'.$i] == 'A') $result_test++; break;
                case 9: if ($_POST['question_'.$i] == 'A') $result_test++; break;
                case 10: if ($_POST['question_'.$i] == 'B') $result_test++; break;
            }
        }
        echo '<p>Вы набрали '.$result_test.'/10</p>';
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А браузер вообще отправляет форму на страницу http://localhost/result.php? Скорей всего он просто перезагружет текущую страницу, так как тег form не понимает атрибут active. `<form active="http://localhost/result.php` надо заменить на `<form action="http://localhost/result.php`.

Comment: да, ошибся в атрибуте из-за своей же невнимательности, спасибо:)